# How to launch fancybox from button onclick event to draw google chart?

Tags: jquery, charts, fancybox, google-visualization

Can we draw a google chart in a pop up fancybox?

I have data shown in a table, and there is a button in each row for showing google chart of each record.

Currently, my chart is always shown in the bottom after the table, but when the record is scroll over the screen, user need scroll to bottom to get the chart view. 
Is it possible to use fancybox or some way solving this inconvenient?

Thanks for any advise!

html:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> data </td>
      ...
      <td>
        <button onclick="showChartByEmpId()"> pie chart </button>
      </td>
   </tr>

</table>

<div class="secondary"> </div>  <!-- showing chart here -->
```

js:

```
function drawPieChart(dataArr, elementId) {
    //dataArr : the data to display
    //elementId : <div> element where to display chart

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArr);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(elementId));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}

function showChart(){
    //alert("readyState=" + xhr2.readyState);

    if(xhr2.readyState == 4) {
        if(xhr2.status == 200){
            var allEmp = xhr2.responseText;
            var empList = JSON.parse(allEmp);

                    ... prepare pieChartDate[] to draw chart ...

                    //create <div> to displaying chart in it    
            $('.secondary').html('<div id="chart_div" height="450" width="450"></div>');
            drawPieChart(pieChartData[0], "chart_div");
      ...

}


function showChartByEmpId(){

    var url = '/CMP/employee/emp.do';

    //create XMLHttpRequest
    xhr = createXHR();

    if( xhr == null ){
        alert("no xhr creted");
        return;
    }          

    var requestData = "action=getOneEmpJSON&empId1=" + escape(empId1) + "&empId2=" + escape(empId2);


    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = showChart;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(requestData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, JFK. It work great! Now I can see the chart in the fancybox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do :

1). hide the `.secondary` div

```
<div class="secondary" style="display:none"></div>
```

2). assign a *class* selector to each button like

```
<button class="doPiechart">pie chart</button>
```

3). bind a `click` event to `each` button and then show the contents of `#chart_div` in fancybox after is created.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".doPiechart").each(function (i) {
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            showChartByEmpId(i);
            $.fancybox("#chart_div");
        }); // on click
    }); // each
});
```

**Notice** that you may need to tweak your `showChartByEmpId()` function to pass the index of the `.each()` method and eventually to include a callback to show fancybox after is completed.

See a simulated behavior in **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AJa5z/)** using [fancybox v2.x](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

**NOTE**: `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+