# How to get get the value of a table cell by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

This thread is the second problem following from my [previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579054/how-to-launch-fancybox-from-button-onclick-event-to-draw-google-chart). After bind the on click event to my show-chart function, I still need to know the value of employee id which is used for getting correct chart data.

Is it possible passing employee id to showChartByEmpId(i) ?

**HTML**

```
<table id="empTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Employee ID </th>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Department  </th>
            <th> Title  </th>
            <th> Show Chart </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> 101 </td>
            <td> John </td>
            <td> R&D </td>
            <td> Engineer </td>
            <td> <button class="doPieChart"> Pie Chart </button> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 102 </td>
            <td> David </td>
            <td> R&D </td>
            <td> Engineer </td>
            <td> <button class="doPieChart"> Pie Chart </button> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="secondary"> </div>
```

**JS**

```
function drawPieChart(i) {
    $('.secondary').html('<div id="chart_div" class="div'+i+'">my graph '+(i+1)+' in fancybox</div>');
}

function showChart(i) {
    drawPieChart(i);
}

function showChartByEmpId(i) {
    showChart(i);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    //How to get emp Id here?
    $(".doPieChart").each(function (i) {
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            showChartByEmpId(i);
            $.fancybox("#chart_div");
        }); // on click
    }); // each
});
```

**Here is my example on** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwGEq/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get emp ID inside the click function

```
 var empID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
```

You don't need .each()

```
$('.doPieChart').on("click", function () {
    var empID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    showChartByEmpId(empID);
    $.fancybox("#chart_div");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
var EmpId;
jQuery(function ($) {
    //How to get emp Id here?
    $(".doPieChart").each(function () {
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            EmpId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
            showChartByEmpId(EmpId);
            $.fancybox("#chart_div");
        }); // on click
    }); // each
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/bqs52/12/

Comment: Thanks for your example, Shakti

Comment: how to put jsfiddle demo link in answer?

Comment: You can click the insert hyperlink icon on top of editor. Past link on the pop up entry.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively just add this var to your existing code

```
var empID = $.trim( $(this).parent().siblings("td").eq(0).text() );
```

So

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //How to get emp Id here?
    $(".doPieChart").each(function (i) {
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            var empID = $.trim( $(this).parent().siblings("td").eq(0).text() );
            showChartByEmpId(empID);
            $.fancybox("#chart_div");
        }); // on click
    }); // each
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PPRq7/)**

**NOTE**: I always prefer the `.eq()` method over the pseudo class `:first` because it's (arguably) faster.